# compiling java from the command line

Tags: java, compilation

I have a package called studentServer which contains two sub packages student and common.
The common folder has references to the student package and i would like to be able to compile this. How could i do this?

```
javac student\*.java - compiles the student package
```

but when i try something similar with the common package errors are thrown - I understand it's something to do with the classpath

```
javac -verbose -classpath "\student" common\*.java
```

But I couldn't get this working. Any help would be great.

http://pastebin.com/m2a2f5d5d - here's the output from the compiler

Comment: Please include the exact output from the compiler, "something with the classpath" is, obviously, a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit vague, but I suspect the classpath for the student code is wrong. Try without the leading backslash.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a directory structure

```
source/
      studentServer/
                   student/
                   common/
classes/
```

And you're in the directory above source, then you want to set the source path to 'source' with the -sourcepath option. You probably also want to use the -d option to tell javac where to put the compiled classes, so they aren't all mixed up with the source:

```
java -d classes -sourcepath source source/studentServer/student/*.java source/studentServer/common/*.java
```

Answer (score -1):

go like this

`c:\>`
 use change directory command cd until you get the desired directory
(ex: `c:\javaEx\proj1\`)

now

`cd javaEx` go like this

`c:\javaEx\proj1\javac *.java`

now compilation done in all java files in the proj1 directory.